# Прозрачная форма на C#, но так чтобы границы и заголовок остались видимыми?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос не новый, на хэшкоде уже подымался, вот таков был ответ:

```
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.AllowTransparency = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;//цвет фона  
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;//он же будет заменен на прозрачный цвет
```

но это делает форму полностью прозрачной, а мне нужно только чтобы внутри было прозрачное, а остальное (заголовок и границы) нет.

Как такой фокус проделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот этот код

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

прячет границу и заголовок окна. Уберите его, и получите прозрачное окно с заголовком и границами.

[Form.FormBorderStyle - свойство](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)

> Стилем границы формы определяется способ отображения ее наружного края.
> Стиль границы способен также влиять на размер и доступность секции строки заголовка формы.

[FormBorderStyle - перечисление](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hw8kes41%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Задает стили границ формы. Это перечисление используется классом Form. Оно предоставляет различные стили формы. **По умолчанию** используется стиль **Sizable**.